# How to rotate Y axis labels in twoord.plot in R?

Tags: r, label, plotrix

Does anyone know how to rotate the Y axis labels in the function twoord.plot in R? Also, how about resizing the font of the Y axis labels?

Comment: Take a look at `?par`. `las` and `cex` are the arguments you're probably looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Under par:
I just picked a random plot that comes with twoord.plot package.

```
 x <- rnorm(100,100,10)
```

First you need to rotate the Y axis:

```
 par(las = 1) # rotates the y axis values for every plot you make from now on unless otherwise specified
```

Next, plot your graph without a Y axis:

```
 plotH(x,x,yaxt = 'n') # no Y axis
```

Then, you need to add the Y axis

```
  axis(2,cex.axis = 0.5) # where 2 specifies the Y axis and 0.5 is half (0.5) of the font size as before.
```